# Unable to get whole row from BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I've been practicing my scraping and everything was going fine but as hard as I try I can't seem to get this specific data I'm looking for.

Structure looks like this

```
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-7 list-field-wrap">
<div class="pull-left">
  <div class="row">
  <div class=" list-field type-field" style="width: 45px"><div class="visible-xs-block visible-sm-block list-label">BIB</div>17584</div>
  <div class=" list-field type-age_class" style="width: 65px"><div class="visible-xs-block visible-sm-block list-label">Division</div>20-24</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is get the 17584 with  class = "visible-xs-block visible-sm-block list-label"

Unfortunately every time I try to select it.  It only returns

```
<div class="visible-xs-block visible-sm-block list-label">BIB</div>
```

This is my code I've been trying to select it

```
bib = soup.find('div', class_="visible-xs-block visible-sm-block list-label"
print(bib)
```

WAS ABLE TO FIGURE IT OUT STRUCTURE START EARLIER.

Comment: Use `list-field type-field` as class and get text.

Answer (score 2):

17584 is not part of the tag with class `visible-xs-block visible-sm-block list-label`:

```
<div class=" list-field type-field" style="width: 45px">
    <div class="visible-xs-block visible-sm-block list-label">
        BIB
    </div>
    17584
</div>
```

Try to select `list-field type-field` instead.

Comment: I've tried that and it just gives me something similar but doesn't give me the 17584 number I need.  It will give me the div class from that point all the way up to BIB</div>

Comment: This is what outputs when I try that.<div class="list-field type-field" style="width: 45px"><div class="visible-xs-block visible-sm-block list-label">BIB</div>BIB</div>